# Appending to a list to remove elements from the list

Tags: python, list, append

I am just testing out how lists work in python and I find it to be very confusing and frustrating. For whatever reason I am getting constant error messages on my code.

```
def listtest(list1,x):
    list2 = []
    count = 0
    for n in list1:
        if list1[count] == x:
            count += 1
        else:
            list2 = list.append(list2,list[count])
            count += 1
    return list2
```

For whatever reason it is either telling me that `list.append` only accepts one argument which is confusing. In the interactions window I can call append with two arguments like so `list.append(list,3)` or whatever and it works flawlessly. The other error I am getting is

```
list2 = list.append(list2,list[count])
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

which is entirely nonsensical to me and not in any way helpful. What is wrong with my code? Why does the interactions window behave differently than the other window? Why won't append work like it does in the interactions window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**  Rewritten after some more careful analysis:

Your immediate problem is `list[count]` which *should* be `list1[count]`. The built-in type `list` can't be indexed (since it's a type, not a list), so you get the `TypeError` about the `__getitem__()` method not being supported.

But even if you had written `list2 = list.append(list2,list1[count])`, you'd still have a problem. What would that line of code do?

1. Append `list1[count]` to `list2`. So far, so good.
2. Assign the result of the call to `list.append()` to `list2`. Since `.append()` is a method that modifies the object it's called on in-place, it always returns `None`.
3. So now `list2` is `None`.
4. The *next*  time you call that line, you'll get another `TypeError` because you can't append anything to `NoneType` objects.

So, what you should have written is

```
list2.append(list1[count])
```

While that would now work, it's an extremely roundabout way to do this. Keeping track of indexes you don't actually need is very unpythonic - the language is much more expressive than that. Don't try to write Java programs in Python. Your function (if your aim really is to create a new list that contains all the objects in `list1` that are the same as `x` - for which I fail to see the point entirely) could be written as

```
def listtest(list1, x):
    return [item for item in list1 if item == x]
```

although that's not much more useful than simply writing

```
list1.count(x)
```

which gives you the number of times `x` appears in `list1`.

Comment: It appears that I can append multiple items at a time. For example I a doing this right now in the interactions window list.appen([1,2,3,4], 5)

Comment: @Jordan: you can call many methods in two ways.  You can call the method of the class -- `list.append` -- and pass it an instance as the first argument, like `a = [1,2,3]; b = 4; list.append(a,b)`, which will turn `a` into `[1,2,3,4]`, or you can call the instance method directly, like `a = [1,2,3]; b = 4; a.append(4)`.  The second one works the same as the first, except that the `a` is automatically included.  You should seldom need to use `list.append` directly.

Comment: @Jordan: Thanks for your comments, I now see the actual problem. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your errors aren't nonsensical, they're trying to point you to the underlying issue.  You should not use `list` as a variable name, because `list` is a built-in type.  Additionally, when you attempt to `append` to a list you do only want to pass one argument.  You can `append` a `tuple` like so:

```
myList.append(('val1', 'val2'))
```

Comment: I am not sure what a tuple is but when I append it it is wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: @Jordan A tuple is a immutable list like data type in python: [Tuple Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to `list2`, use `list2.append()`, not `list.append()`.

Comment: Oh that is helpful, I didn't see anywhere in the documentation that the variable is what goes there I thought it was just a named function.

Comment: `append` is a method of the built-in list class.

Comment: I am still getting some odd error message though "   list2 = list2.append(list1[count])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: @Jordan: `append` acts in-place and returns `None`, it doesn't make a copy and then return that.  Simply use `list2.append(list1[count])`.

Comment: @DSM That is what I am using actualy and it does not work. Are you saying that I do not want to assign anything? Why would that cause an error? Is it like telling python to assign twice?

Comment: @Jordan: that error message means that `list2` is None.  That would happen if you assigned the name `list2` to the result of `append`.  Look, go into the interpreter.  Type `a = [1,2,3]` and then `b = a.append(4)` and then `print a` and `print b` (or `print(a)`/`print(b)` if you're using Python 3).  Calling `append` will change the list and return the object None.

Answer (score 0):

You can only append *one* item at a time to list. You can extend() a list with the items of a second list which basically means that you append each individual item of the second list to the first one. What is here hard to understand? The list API is very well documented and clear.

Comment: It is hard to understand why it is telling me that list.append only accepts one argument when I am giving it that.

Comment: Also I have no idea what API even is.